How to display pdf in full available screen size?
I code in react-native-pdf, i want to display pdf horizondally but my pdf sizes are in a4 sheet size
but i want to display pdf in full available height of the screen as well as width like in  component we can stretch the image to take up the entire size like that
it can but react-native-pdf module or native code
it can but react-native-pdf module or native code
help me display the pdf in full screen size
screenshtot of the pdf

Thanks for the info,
clearly i undershoot

Referring to the react-native-pdf documentation. In order to display a PDF that will adapt to the screen dimensions, you need to use CSS styles. These should look similar to those listed below:
pdf: {
        flex:1,
        width:Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height:Dimensions.get('window').height,
    }

These will make the PDF document stretch to the dimensions of the screen.

can give examples with Pdf probs too
because it not working
i want to stretch the pdf page to fill entire page
